# WSE 2.0 SoapHttpRouter: Is it possible to route soap messages with already attached client certificate?

Tags: soap, web-services

Will the client certificate be preserved after routing the call via an SoapHttpRouter?

if not, how to route a message with already attached clientcertificate or: how to reattach an certificate at the side of soaphttprouter again? (not the best solution.. :-( )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i´m aware of that..

btw.. the cause for my problem is that the (protocol-layer) client certificate which i "attach" to the webservice-call is getting loosed after passing my SoapHttpRouter-ancestor class.. i think that there is no way to workaround this. May someone knows a solution?

Comment: @krie: can you say what you are responding to? What is it that you are aware of? That WSE is obsolete?

Comment: Hi John, i mean i am aware of that WSE is obsolete. Btw now i have to use another solution, because i can forget forwarding / routing requests with an WSE SoapRouter if i want to have client certificates attached to those requests. It doesn´t work.

Comment: I don't see the text of what you were responding to. Did I have a comment saying it's obsolete, and is that what you're responding to? I think someone may be deleting such comments of mine.